# Given the lines $r_1, r_2$ find a point $A$ in $r_1$ and a point $B$ in $r_2$ such that the vector $\vec{AB}$ is orthogonal to both lines

Tags: linear-algebra

[Original problem statement (In Spanish)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PNkZ.png)

**Given the lines $r_1$, $r_2$ find a point $A$ in $r_1$ and a point $B$ in $r_2$ such that the vector $\vec{AB}$ is orthogonal to both lines**

I've determined r1, r2 to be:

$r_1: (7,0,7) + \lambda(-2,1,-1)$

$r_2: (2,5,0) + \alpha(0,0,1)$

Then, I went ahead and found the normal vector $\,\vec{n}\,$ between each line's vector (Through cross product)

$\vec{n}=(-1,-2,0)$

Now, I'm not sure where to go from here. Through geogebra I've checked that the vector n is in fact orthogonal to both lines, and that both lines are correct.

I tried through the following line equation:

$(x_1,y_1,z_1) + \lambda(-1,-2,0) = (x_2,y_2,z_2)$

But I got nowhere with this.

Comment: **Just an insight**: $A$ and  $B$ are chosen such that $AB$ is the least distance between $r_1$ and $r_2$

Comment: Yes, I was able to gather that much and A and B are the only points on the lines where, when applied the normal vector, the vector will cross both lines. But I still wasn't able to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Take a general vector $\vec{AB}$

$$\vec{AB}=\begin{pmatrix}5-2\lambda\\-5+\lambda\\7-\lambda-\alpha\end{pmatrix}.$$
Now you can proceed in two ways:

1. Notice that $\vec{n}$ and $\vec{AB}$ must be parallel and hence $\mu\vec{n}=\vec{AB}$ and now you solve for the parameters.
2. $\vec{AB}$ by definition must be perpendicular to both $\vec{d_{r_1}}$ and $\vec{d_{r_2}}$, thus take the dot product must be zero with both, leading you to a simple 2 variabile system of equations.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Form the parametric equations for both lines. Now since the vector AB is orthogonal to both the lines, use the property that orthogonal vectors have a dot product 0. Use this property and dot the vector AB twice; with the direction vector of the first line and the second line respectively to get the desired parameter values and hence the required points. Have a nice day.